# Default server block keeps loading instead of the server block which has the website files

Tags: nginx

It's my fresh installation of nginx on Ubuntu so I haven't messed up much and most of the tutorials are taken from DigitalOcean website. I have set up two server blocks (first is the default and second is for my website) but due to some issue, the default server block keeps loading even if I call for my website which is in secondary server block. My website is yoalfaaz.com and if I try to load it, then a file from default server loads up.

To be even more clear, the files of `/var/www/html` keeps loading, instead, I want to load files of `/var/www/yoalfaaz.com/html`.

Here's the `sites-available/yoalfaaz.com` file

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;

        root /var/www/yoalfaaz.com/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name yoalfaaz.com www.yoalfaaz.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
        }
}
```

And here's the error.log message

```
2018/02/18 06:47:02 [error] 28275#28275: *1656 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 47.89.22.200, server: [IP for server], request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "www.yoalfaaz.com", referrer: "https://www.yoalfaaz.com"
```

I have also used the command `nginx -t` and everything is good with that. So can you please tell what the issue is here?

Comment: Look to see what files exist in the `/var/www/yoalfaaz.com/html` directory.

Comment: Good that error message. My first two guesses are you don't have an index.html or similar, or Nginx doesn't have permission to read the files.

Comment: @MichaelHampton There are the source files for my website.

Comment: @Tim I think nginx is still serving default server block as the main address. So even if I types yoalfaaz.com then also I was showng `Welcome of nginx` page which was on default server block. I then removed that file (Welcome to nginx) and after that I am constantly getting 403 forbidden.

Comment: So... Nginx was showing a file, you delete that file and made no configuration changes, and the file now isn't showing?

Comment: @Tim yes that's correct. I just deleted that file on default server block and made no other changes.

Comment: That you deleted a file and it stopped working is a really big clue. Put a file back in that location and see if it starts working again. If it's showing a file from the wrong folder that's a clue. Your question is very difficult or impossible to answer with the information provided and risks being closed because of that. Please edit it to be more clear and provide more information.

Comment: @Tim I created a file in default server block and now 403 forbidden error is gone. You can check it on yoalfaaz.com and now I am also editing the question to provide better info.

Comment: You should be able to work it out from here. Please answer your own question once you have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some problem with creating symbolic links to the files in `sites-enabled`. So I removed the files in `sites-enabled` from command

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoalfaaz.com
```

Then I again created symbolic links using the command

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoalfaaz.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

and everything started to work again.